# How to change subtitles/caption font size in JWPlayer?

Tags: fonts, size, jwplayer, caption, subtitle

How to change the **subtitles** or **caption** font size property in **JWPlayer** Configuration to make font size default with some choice value.

Answer (score 0):

When Configuring the JWPlayer Setup in our code as mentioned in the official Documentation. [Link here](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-player-configuration-reference)

We can set fontSize;
Insert fontSize property .setCaptions() after setup with your desired value as in below example 12px

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
  "playlist": "https://cdn.jwplayer.com/v2/media/hWF9vG66",
  "height": 360,
  "width": 640,
  "autostart": "viewable",
  "advertising": {
    "client": "vast",
    "tag": "http://adserver.com/vastTag.xml"
  }
}).setCaptions({
     'fontSize' : 12
});
```